# items flying one after another does not work in tabs in presentation with xaringan theme

Tags: xaringan

`--` usually is inserted in between two items for showing one item after another by clicking the mouse.  However, it does not work in tabs.

```
<!-- Tab links -->
<div class="tab">
  <button class="tablinks active" onclick="tablabel(event, 'section1')">tabA</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="tablabel(event, 'section2')">tabB</button>

</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="section1" class="tabcontent" style="display:block">

item A

--

item B
</div>

...
```

It works in tabA, but does not work in tabB, or tabC, ...

When returning from tabB to tabA.  The content under tabA disappeared.